# Interpret carriage returns programatically in bash

Tags: bash, carriage-return

When bash displays strings, it interprets the carriage return '^M'

```
$ echo "1234^Mab"
ab34
```

I have a script that needs access to the interpreted string "ab34". But I can't find any way to do this. The output stream of the echo command still contains the carriage return character, which means that if a script reads the output, it will still see "1234^Mab", even though the shell displays the string "ab34".

Removing the carriage return is not good enough; It does not result in the string "ab34".

```
$ echo "1234^Mab" | tr -d '\r'
1234ab
```

Converting the carriage return to a unix-style newline character doesn't produce the desired result either:

```
$ echo "1234^Mab" | sed 's/^M/\n/'
1234
ab
```

Comment: The string isn't "interpreted" at all; your eyes simply aren't fast enough to see the string 1234 on the screen before the terminal repositions the cursor at the beginning of the line before printing the final two characters over top the first two. A fancier terminal might not even erase the first two, instead giving you a typewrite-style overlay of `a/1` and `b/2`.

Comment: @karakfa That's exactly the same as `var=$'1234\rab'`. The carriage return is still in the output stream that's captured; it's only the way the terminal displays that makes it appear to be "ab34". You can verify this by looking at the expansion `${#var}`.

Comment: To reiterate for clarity. The **only** place you have the string `ab34` is on the displayed screen. And the **only** reason you have that is because the `^M`/`\r` moved the output cursor back to the start of the line and then kept printing (and overwrote) the `12`. That's a feature of how the terminal works. That's nothing about the string itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`col -b`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/col.1.html) command to interpret cursor control sequences and return the visible output.

```
echo $'1234\rab' | col -b
```

This handles about a dozen different cursor motion sequences, not just carriage return.

Comment: Yes, this works.  `var=$(echo -e "1234\rab"| col -b); echo ${#var}` prints 4.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script that "emulates" the carriage-return by processing the input argument character by character. The output is built character by character too, resetting the output index when CR is encountered.

```
#! /bin/bash

arg="$1"
out=""
cr=$'\r'

j=0
for ((i=0; i<${#arg}; i++)) ; do
  char=${arg:$i:1}
  if [[ $char = $cr ]] ; then
    j=0
  else
    tmp="${out:0:$j}"$char
    ((j++))
    out="$tmp${out:$j}"
  fi
  # echo "$out" # to see it in progress
done
echo "Final: $out"
```

Example:

```
$ ./t.sh 123456$'\r'abcde$'\r'.:.
1
12
123
1234
12345
123456
123456
a23456
ab3456
abc456
abcd56
abcde6
abcde6
.bcde6
.:cde6
.:.de6
Final: .:.de6
```

Comment: And now that I think about it, there's probably a much more efficient solution by splitting the string on `\r` and rebuilding based on that rather than char by char...

Comment: I was working on that, but gave up when I saw Barmar's answer.

Comment: Wow indeed, much more elegant. Had never heard of `col`.